# Python boolean evaluation order

Tags: python

I'm working with linked lists in Python and couldn't quite figure out the error statement it was putting out.

This is my code to increment through the nodes from the head of the list:

```
    while current.next_node is not None and value > current.next_node.data:
        current = current.next_node
    current.next_node = Node(value, current.next_node)
```

While the above works, this doesn't:

```
    while value > current.next_node.data and current.next_node is not None:
        current = current.next_node
    current.next_node = Node(value, current.next_node)
```

I figured that as long as the while statement evaluated to either true or false, that it would behave accordingly. Instead, it throws an error when it tries to run `value > current.next_node.data` alone and realizes that the current.next_node doesn't exist.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python does **short circuit evaluation** which is why you're seeing the behavior you are. This comes into play in `and` and `or` clauses similarly.

With `and` clauses, if the expression on the left side evaluates to `False` there is no way the entire statement can evaluate to `True` (False and anything is False) so it doesn't bother to evaluate the expression on the right-hand side. If the left-hand side of expression is `True`, then the right-hand one is evaluated to see what the full expression should be.

Similarly, with `or` clauses, if the expression on the left evaluates to `True`, there is no way the entire statement can be `False` since True or anything is always True. So again, the right-hand expression will not be evaluated. But if the left-hand expression is False, the right-hand one must be evaluated to know the value of the entire expression.

You can see this in action here:

```
>>> def foo():
...     print('foo')
...     return 0

>>> def bar():
...     print('bar')
...     return 1

>>> foo() and bar()
foo
0

>>> bar() and foo()
bar
foo
0
```

Comment: I see. That makes sense. Thank you.Please correct me if I'm wrong, but the way C evaluates is different, right? With C, it evaluates the entirety of the clause?

Comment: @choijam Nope, C does short circuiting too!

Comment: So what's really happening under the hood is: TRUE and TRUE = TRUE, TRUE and FALSE = FALSE, FALSE AND = automatically FALSE. Thank you, this is valuable information.

Answer (score 3):

Arguments evaluate left to right and there is a "principle of economy".

- In an "and" clause, the first that gives a False value stops the evaluation and returns False.
- In an "or" clause, the First that returns True stops the evaluation and returns True.

You can use it in your favor, by first evaluating the "safety" condition and then the other.

```
while current.next_node is not None and value > current.next_node.data:
    current = current.next_node
current.next_node = Node(value, current.next_node)
```

In this way, the failure of the first condition will always stop the evaluation. And if it returns true, then the second will execute correctly.

In the other version, you may be trying to access `current.next_node.data` without the safety. And if current is None, it will trigger an exception.

Comment: i see. that makes sense. So because the next_node didn't exist, it was throwing an attribute error when it called next_node.data. But in the first case, because I was checking for the existence of the next_node, when it realized it didn't exist, it exited out of that while loop not even running the second condition... thanks!